# Android layout - set rounded corner radius relative to screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm using the following as a background for a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

but the rounded-ness looks very different on a 4" 800x480 screen than it does on a 4.7" 1280x720 screen. Is there any way to set the radius relative to the screen?

Comment: No. You don't have a % option. dp (= dip) is your best choice to be density (= resolution) aware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good question, I do not know of a neat way to do this with XML (if using dip values is insufficient), however you could create your drawable programmatically and do some math based on the screen size to achieve what you want.

```
// Create a drawable
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
// Get the screen size
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
// Do some math to get the radius value to scale
int radius = (int) Math.round(width * height / 100000);
// Set the corner radius
shape.setCornerRadius(radius);
// Apply shape as background
setBackground(shape);
```

So for a 1280x800 screen this would be width * height = 1024000 divided by 100000 rounded gives you a 10px radius. However on a 800x480 screen the radius would be 4px. This doesn't take into account physical size of the screen however, so if this is an issue you can get the physical size in inches:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double inches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Then you can factor this value also, for example:

```
int radius = (int) Math.round(width * height * inches / 500000);
```

So now for a 1280x800 4" screen this would be width * height * 4 = 4096000 divided by 500000 rounded gives you an 8px radius. On a 800x480 10" screen this would be width * height * 10 = 4096000 divided by 500000 rounded which also gives you an 8px radius.

I know this is a dirty hack and you may need to tweak the math to get it to scale perfectly, but I believe this is the only way that scaling the radius can be achieved.